# Project won't update R.java?

Tags: android, r.java-file

My main class folder was named `com.test`, I changed it to `com.myApplication`, and now when I add objects to my layout my `R.java` won't get updated, all objects that I had before work fine, and they are in `R.java`, but anything new that I create won't get added to `R.java`
Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: I solved the problem.
I had some errors in my layouts due to removing some images.
I fixed those problem, and it generated the R.Java again

Comment: Great.  Please provide your comment (preferably with more detail) as an answer and accept it so that future users can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had some errors in my layouts due to removing some images. I fixed those problem, and it generated the R.Java again